# Migrating DTS packages to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, dts

I need to migrate all the DTS packages to MS SQL Server 2016. What are the contents of DTS pacakages. Are there any differences in SQL statements like Insert, Update, Delete etc. What are the things I should be aware of to upgrade the DTS packages to SSIS? How I can migrate DTS packages to SQL Server 2016?

Comment: The products are substantially different. If your DTS is mainly running SQL statements it should be straightfoward to migrate but if yu have data pumps, these are completely different. How many packages do you need to migrate and are there many tasks other than 'execute SQL'. You're probably better of with a complete redesign.

Comment: Lets divert the topic, do you have any idea about Vertime Web Server OS Migration?

Comment: Lets not - how about you finish this question and open a new question on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if Microsoft provided Migration Wizard in SQL 2016 to migrate DTS to SSIS but I know for sure that its an option in SQL 2005 and 2008. So your best bet could be migrate to SSIS using some SQL 2005 or 2008 installation (Use DTS Migration Wizard). Once packages are in SSIS 2005 or 2008 format its very easy to upgrade them to SSIS 2016 format....

Word of caution.... DTS and SSIS is very different and no upgrade wizard can be full proof so there will be lot of hand edits specially if you have ActiveX scripts in DTS.

If its not too much code in DTS then this would be good opportunity to re-write it so you can learn SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot migrate DTS (the program that proceeded SSIS) to SQL Server 2016. DTS is based on Activex and MS is treating DTS like a bad dream. You cannot migrate the package (there are no tools to go to 2016 ) and you cannot (you could in 2005) run DTS packages in 2016. SSIS and DTS are radically different and you are in for a bit of a learning curve to transition to SSIS. There are third party tools that claim to transform DTS packages to SSIS but the ones I have seen make it very challenging to maintain the new translated package. You will have to refactor and rewrite the programs in SSIS.